# clear part of a pygame surface where a cursor is

Tags: python, cursor, pygame, surface

I have a "you have a high score, enter your initials" screen for my game, and it works.  Then I decided I wanted a blinking cursor where the initials would be, and it would start in initial one (x,y), and then when that was entered, move to initial 2 (x,y).  The problem is that if you press a letter when the cursor has drawn the blue rectangle it leaves it on the screen, and I need to clear just that area.  Is there a way to do this?  Here is my initial entry code and the cursor blinking code:

```
def update_highscores(index):

    background.fill(BLACK)

    # co-ords for inital entry

    ix = []

    ix1 = (background.get_width()/2) - 25
    ix2 = ix1 + 20
    ix3 = ix2 + 20

    ix.append(ix1)
    ix.append(ix2)
    ix.append(ix3)

    iy= 140

    inits = []
    initsurf = []

    title = "You have a high score"
    textsurface = write(title)
    background.blit(textsurface, ( (background.get_width()/2) - (textsurface.get_width()/2), 60))

    enterinits = "enter your initials"
    textsurface = write(enterinits)
    background.blit(textsurface, ( (background.get_width()/2) - (textsurface.get_width()/2), 90))

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

    for c in range(3):
        letter = -1
        while letter == -1:
            blink_cursor(ix[c], iy)
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(25)

            letter = getkey()   
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()

        if letter <= 127:
            inits. append(chr(letter))

        elif inkey == K_RETURN:
            break

        initsurf.append(write(inits[c]))
        background.blit(initsurf[c], (ix[c], iy))
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

    initStr = inits[0] + inits[1] + inits[2]
    highnames[index] = initStr

def blink_cursor(x,y):
    global highcursor
    highcursor +=1
    highcursor = highcursor%11

    if highcursor == 5:
        pygame.draw.rect(background, BLUE, (x, y, 20, 20), 0)
    elif highcursor == 10:
        pygame.draw.rect(background, BLACK, (x, y, 20, 20), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: simply set highcursor to nine and call blink_cursor:

```
if letter <= 127:
        inits.append(chr(letter).upper())
        highcursor = 9
        blink_cursor(ix[c], iy)
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

As blink_cursor increments the cursor count by 1 to ten first, and when the count is ten it draws a black rectangle.  Sorted.